# mysql sort by column with addotinal parameter

Tags: mysql, sorting

I'm not sou sure if this is possible at all but is worth asking the question.

I would like to sort table by drivers id's

```
SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY driverid DESC
```

there is another table 'drivers' with the list of drivers where each driver has corresponding que number:

```
driver | driverid | queno
-------------------
drv1   | 15       | 3
drv2   | 30       | 1
drv3   | 40       | 2
```

so from 'test' db I can take driverid. But I would like to sort out this listing not by driverid but by queno. Is there any way to bring queno to the game...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SELECT * FROM test JOIN drivers ON test.driverid=drivers.driverid ORDER BY queno DESC

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM test t
LEFT JOIN drivers d ON t.driverid = d.driverid 
ORDER BY d.queno DESC
```